# proc_open(): fork failed - Out of memory

Tags: php, docker, composer-php

I'm running the following command in composer

`composer create-project pyrocms/pyrocms website`

which is leading to an error

> The archive may contain identical file names with different capitalization (which fails on case insensitive filesystems) Unzip with unzip command failed, falling back to ZipArchive class

and the subject error as well. I'm not sure which is causing which. But I'm kind of lost as to how to fix it as I'm running in a Docker environment with the following

- unlimited resources
- memory_limit = -1
- timeout limit > 2000

I'm running in a Docker Linux armv7 envirnoment using composer 1.7.3.

Comment: So, do you have enough free phisical memory?

Comment: @Robert i believe so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:
https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#proc-open-fork-failed-errors

```
/bin/dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/swap.1 bs=1M count=1024 
/sbin/mkswap /var/swap.1 
/sbin/swapon /var/swap.1
```